# How can I get my Wiki to have the same in-built referencing tools as Wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki

My [Wiki](http://health-and-medicine.wikia.com/wiki/Health_and_Medicine_Wiki), is still very much in its infancy, and I would like to know how I could replicate the referencing tools (like the autofill options for [PMID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubMed)s and [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier)s) and import the [referencing templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Citation) (i.e., `cite journal`, `cite web`, `cite news`, `cite book`, *etc.*). I have tried copy-pasting to my Wiki using the source code, but that did not work, see for instance [this page](http://health-and-medicine.wikia.com/wiki/User:Fuse809/sandbox) where I have tried to utilize the `cite journal` template. I am especially interested in the `cite journal` template. If any additional details are required please feel free to ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The `{{#invoke}}` syntax is interpreted by [the Scribunto extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), so you'll need to have that installed.

You will also need to copy any of the `#invoke`d modules. In this case, that seems to be [Module:Citation/CS1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Citation/CS1) and possibly other modules that module uses.